# Why do we need $|\cdot|$ in this statement: $f \in L^p \iff |f|^p \in L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am somewhat confused about the following statement: $$f \in L^p \iff |f|^p \in L^1$$

Why do we need the $|\cdot|$ if we have it in $$  ||f ||_p := \bigg(\int |f| ^p\bigg)^{\frac 1 p}$$
anyway?

What breaks down if we drop $|\cdot|$ and write $$f \in L^p \iff f^p \in L^1$$

Comment: What does $f^p$ mean when $f$ is not positive ... negative or complex?  Writing $|f|^p$ insures that we don't have to think about that.

Comment: Not having to think about that is not a reason.

Comment: Nothing happens in the equivalence below. Now, for the definition of the norm, you really want it to be a non-negative number, mainly because you want it to be norm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Franklin.vp: Of course it is.

Comment: Of course it is not! Just define what is the $p$-th power and compute. you can break the integral for the branching and that's it. Besides, what would be your answer for the need when $p$ is natural? Definitely it is nothing about having trouble defining $f^p$. The absolute value is not important to define $L^p$ as lebesgue integrable is the same as absolutely Lebesgue integrable. The only place it is needed it to get a norm.

Comment: I agree with Franklin.vp. Isn't it the case that $f \in L^1$ $\iff$ $|f| \in L^1$?

Comment: Are there books on real analysis that work with complex-valued $L^p$-functions $f$ and use $f^p$ instead of $|f|^p$? I don't think I've seen such texts.

Comment: I doubt it. Since the norm is the star of the picture, you want the absolute value there. There is no need for the pain of not putting it to define $L^p$ and then put it to define the norm.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value is not necessary for the definition of $L^p$ as elements such that $f^p$ is integrable. The reason is that a function is Lebesgue integrable iff its absolute value is integrable.

Now, when you are going to define $||f||_p$ you want it to be a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29). If you don't put the absolute value in the definition you are not going to get a norm.

Comment: It is not true that "a function is integrable iff its absolute value is integrable": on a set of finite measure let $f$ take just the values $\pm 1$, with $1$ on a nonmeasurable set and $-1$ on the complement of the nonmeasurable set.  Then $|f|$ is integrable while $f$ is not.

Comment: A bon entendeur, demi- mot. Add measurable to even begin to talk about defining integral, please.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement that you quoted came from a context where *real*-valued function spaces were under consideration, then the answer is given by GEdgar's comment: If $f$ has negative values and $p$ is not an integer, then $f^p$ isn't available as a real-valued function.  If, on the other hand, the function spaces consist of *complex*-valued functions, then $f^p$ might not be single-valued. That's not a major problem, because you just have to choose a single-valued determination of it, and the quoted statement without the absolute value will be true for any reasonable choice. But the author would have to say something about making that choice, and it's quicker just to avoid the issue by using the absolute value, especially since, as Franklin.vp pointed out, the absolute value is what's relevant to the norm.